Visualization of GTFS stops and routes (or shapes) in OpenTripPlanner
Example Screenshot from QGIS
I tried to set up and test my own OTP2 server using the tutorial from https://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Tutorial/
The server works fine, and I am also able to create an itinerary. However, I would like to visualize the original stops and routes in the OSM as well, as can be done in ArcMap or QGIS.
I have gone through quite a few articles/webpages, but can't seem to find what I want.
Any help at all is highly appreciated.
